# When should you use a mutex over a channel?

Tags: go, concurrency

For the past few weeks I've been wrestling with one (not-so) simple question:

#### When is it best to use `sync.Mutex` and, conversely, when is it best use a `chan`?

It seems that for a lot of problems either strategy is interchangeable with the other - *and that's just the problem!*

Take [this video](https://youtu.be/QDDwwePbDtw?t=2m55s) found in the Golang documentation.
Below, I've taken the liberty to dictate the code in the playground and also translate it to a `sync.Mutex` equivalent.

#### Is there a certain problem - encountered in the real world - that warrants the use of one other?

Notes:

- I am a huge fan of [this use of `chan`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/bbe10f4f7745000c121b629ff68e81bba5a497f6/src/matcher.go#L153) and struggle to think of a more elegant implementation using `sync.Mutex`.
- It's worth noting that the `chan` implementation does more work in the same time (reaches 12)*

Playgrounds:

- [Chan implementation](https://play.golang.org/p/u2pAJ6soNd)
- [Mutex implementation](https://play.golang.org/p/lxtd2yQYe0)

Ping/pong with `chan`:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Ball struct { hits int }

func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)
    
    table <- new(Ball)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    <-table
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

Ping/pong with `sync.Mutex`:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

type Ball struct { hits int }

var m =  sync.Mutex{}

func main() {
    ball := new(Ball)
    go player("ping", ball)
    go player("pong", ball)
    
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}

func player(name string, ball *Ball) {
    for {
        m.Lock()
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        m.Unlock()

    }
}
```

Comment: These are different tools. Mutexes sequentialize access to a resource. On the other hand channels are for orchestrating computations between goroutines. There are a plethora of patterns that can be done using channels that are meaningless when we talk about a Mutex. For example channels can help with constructing pipelines which will stop, when we close the channel. Or patterns like fan-in and fan-out. Or having a M:N job dispatching.

Comment: Your contrived example that is relatively similar with both is the exception to the rule. It's usually very clear where you need "mutual exclusion" rather than synchronization and communication. When in doubt, the simpler implementation is usually what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang, how to share value - message or mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521587/golang-how-to-share-value-message-or-mutex)

Comment: You should also note that your example implementations don't do the same thing. The channel implementation coordinates the "ping-pong" back and forth be sending a message, while the mutex implementation just provides mutual exclusion around the ball variable which results in no deterministic ordering.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MutexOrChannel

Comment: Channel can be used for mutex. in this case, it is just what channel used for. but channel may a little slower than mutex.  you can compare the hits at the end.

Answer (score 15):

In Go, channels are fantastic, and you can use them to communicate between goroutines. However, you may want to use the `sync.Mutex` in some circumstances for convenience.
These circumstances are like the following:

- Guarding an internal state
- Cache problems
- For better performance

Here are three [examples and explanations](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/mutex-examples-in-go-ad7c440461a4)

1. A simple counter

[image]

2. Ping Pong Game

[image]

3. The Simplest Cache

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you for that!

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some example channel usecases:

- **Limit concurrent tasks number** (e.g. number of running goroutines) using buffered channel capacity (and/or length)
- **Transferring ownership** of an object (one and only one goroutine writes to it while no other goroutines reading it)
- **Coordination, synchronization**, sending signals, and data.

Some example primitives usecases:

- **Guarding internal state** of a struct (with e.g. `sync.Mutex`, or `sync.RWMutex`)
- **Performance critical** (algorithm and use case dependent, not a general rule)

---

### Examples

To make it clear, imagine we need a one second counter, so in the following examples we count for a second then print the counter value to see how fast it counts:

```
No |         Count |       Method
------------------------------------------------------
 1 |     17_729_027 | Using sync.RWMutex for increment   
 2 |     12_180_741 | Using channel for increment    
 3 |    106_743_095 | Using channel for timer 
 4 |    104_178_671 | Using time.AfterFunc and channel sync
```

Note: go version go1.13.5 linux/amd64

---

Codes:

1 - Using `sync.RWMutex` for increment:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var i rwm
    go func() {
        for {
            i.inc() // free running counter
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(i.read()) // sampling the counter
}

type rwm struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    i int
}

func (l *rwm) inc() {
    l.Lock()
    defer l.Unlock()
    l.i++
}
func (l *rwm) read() int {
    l.RLock()
    defer l.RUnlock()
    return l.i
}
```

---

2 - Using channel for increment:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    ch <- 1
    timeout := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-timeout.C:
            timeout.Stop()
            break loop
        default:
            ch <- 1 + <-ch
        }
    }

    println(<-ch)
}
```

---

3 - Using channel for timer:

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        timeout := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
        defer timeout.Stop()
        i := 1
        for {
            select {
            case <-timeout.C:
                ch <- i
                return
            default:
                i++
            }
        }
    }()

    println(<-ch)
}
```

---

4 - Using `time.AfterFunc` and channel sync:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d := 1 * time.Second
    i := uint64(0)
    ch := make(chan struct{})

    time.AfterFunc(d, func() {
        close(ch)
    })

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-ch:
            break loop
        default:
            i++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(i) // 104_178_671
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're comparing. The first example calls `Lock()` on each increment. The second example is not using channels for increment, it uses channels only for checking the timer. It would be more fair to pass each value through the channel (and it would make channel 2-4x slower) - [example](https://gist.github.com/quasilyte/009edaf14aad08f6d1997b026c63c0a0).

Comment: See the new edit, this is a complete rewrite, just for your comment, thanks for the comment. It seems there is no other **concurrent safe** way to increment unless using a channel for synchronization or Locked increment.

Comment: There is no much sense in benchmarking mutexes performance when there is only one goroutine involved. To benchmark it properly one should use multiple goroutines so lock will be acquired.