# GoLang net/http CookieJar Headers Persisting Across Functions

Tags: go, cookies, httpcookie

I have a function that distributes tasks for requests to make unique requests which also need unique cookies.

```golang
func DistributeTasks(url string) error {
       // redacted code 

    responseCh := make(chan utilities.WebsiteData, len(distributedCoupons))
    errorCh := make(chan error)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var cookieJarMutex sync.Mutex

    for _, couponArray := range distributedCoupons {
        wg.Add(1)
        CookieJar, err := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})
        if err != nil {
            cookieJarMutex.Lock()
            errorCh <- err
            cookieJarMutex.Unlock()
        }
        go func(couponArray utilities.TaskData) {
            defer wg.Done()

            cookieJarMutex.Lock() // Acquire the mutex
            _, err = TaskToDistribute(parsedURL, couponArray, responseCh, errorCh, CookieJar)
            cookieJarMutex.Unlock() // Release the mutex

            if err != nil {
                cookieJarMutex.Lock()
                errorCh <- err
                cookieJarMutex.Unlock()
            }
        }(couponArray)

    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(responseCh)
        close(errorCh)
    }()

        // Channels are handled here, also redacted
}
```

This distributes the task fine, but even after creating different cookie jars, the cookies pile up onto each request (basically having all the cookies into one jar), and only after a few tasks are made the webserver starts returning cookie too large errors (confirmed with the cookie being over 20,000+ characters). While looking into it, the session tokens are added each time from each individual request (all session tokens are in the same jar).

Here is the code making the HTTP Request:

```golang
for _, task:= range taskData.tasks{
    // Prepare GraphQL to be sent off to test a promo code
    GraphQLQuery := CreateGraphQLQuery(taskDataV2, parsedSessionCookie, testProduct_ProductID)
    // Test Coupon
    CouponValue, err := TestCoupon(*parsedURL, GraphQLQuery, &taskData.ProxyURL, CookieJar)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    // Redacted return code
    // Wait Time Between to avoid ratelimiting
    time.Sleep(350 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

TestCoupon:

```golang
func TestCoupon(domain url.URL, GraphQLquery string, proxyURL *url.URL, CookieJar *cookiejar.Jar) (util.PromoCode, error) {
    var parsedData util.ShopifyPromoResponse

    GRAPHQL_URL := ParsedURLtoString(domain) + "/testData"
    // Make the Request
    client := &http.Client{
        Jar: CookieJar,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
        },
    }
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, GRAPHQL_URL, strings.NewReader(GraphQLquery))
    PrintHeaders(&request.Header)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    request.Header = util.Headers
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
        // Redacted return code
}
```

This is a very weird issue and I cannot figure out! Thanks!

I have attempted (as shown above) having different CookieJars for each function call, which did not work as well as initializing the CookieJar in the function itself. The functions are having the same session tokens in the cookies as they are called. (Function call 5 will have all session tokens from function call 1, 2, 3, and 4) Function call refers the goroutine called from the distributor.

Comment: What does `util.Headers` include? (the one used in `request.Header = util.Headers`)

Comment: Headers includes basic browser headers as seen [here.](https://gist.github.com/makors/97d0f81ab84475f618cb4ff8d1a8f00c)

Answer (score 0):

Since `util.Headers` does not contain a `Cookie` header (per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76696405/golang-net-http-cookiejar-headers-persisting-across-functions#comment135221793_76696405)). that should mean that the `http.Client` is indeed using the `CookieJar` for each individual request.

You need to debug this issue: print out the contents of the `CookieJar` at different points in your code to confirm that the cookies are not being shared across different `CookieJars`.
You can print out the contents of a `CookieJar` (name and value) with something like this:

```golang
func printCookies(jar *cookiejar.Jar, u *url.URL) {
    for _, cookie := range jar.Cookies(u) {
        fmt.Printf("Cookie: %s = %s\n", cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
    }
}
```

You could call this function in your `TestCoupon` function immediately before and after `client.Do(request)`. That would let you see what cookies are being sent in the request, and what cookies have been received and stored in the `CookieJar` after the request.

Check also if any of the request's response cookies have a `Domain` attribute set. If the `Domain` attribute is set, the cookie is also valid for all subdomains of that domain.

---

Note: you have used `sync.Mutex` to handle errors with a `cookieJarMutex` which is fine, but there is no real need to protect access to the error channel with a mutex. Channels are designed to be safe to use concurrently by multiple goroutines, and you could just as well send errors to the `errorCh` channel without the need to lock a mutex:

```golang
if err != nil {
    errorCh <- err
}
```

See also "**[When should you use a mutex over a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47312029/6309)**"

---

> But when printing out `response.Request.Header` (the request made), the cookie header provided is upwards of 20,000+ characters long, meaning that all the `CookirJars` are combining somehow. This is shown after a few requests, the web server starts errors as the cookie is too large.

I can suggest trying to create a completely new client for each goroutine. In your existing code, you are sharing the `http.Client` across goroutines.
To isolate this, try and create a new client with its own cookie jar within the goroutine.

```golang
for _, couponArray := range distributedCoupons {
    wg.Add(1)

    go func(couponArray utilities.TaskData) {
        defer wg.Done()
        
        CookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})

        client := &http.Client{
            Jar: CookieJar,
            // Additional fields...
        }

        _, err := TaskToDistribute(parsedURL, couponArray, responseCh, errorCh, client)

        if err != nil {
            errorCh <- err
        }
    }(couponArray)
}
```

That approach creates a unique client and cookie jar for each goroutine, which might help in your scenario.

It implies the `TaskToDistribute` function would need to be modified to accept a `*http.Client` as an argument instead of a `*cookiejar.Jar`, and use that client for making HTTP requests.

```golang
func TaskToDistribute(parsedURL string, couponArray utilities.TaskData, responseCh chan utilities.WebsiteData, errorCh chan error, client *http.Client) (*utilities.WebsiteData, error) {

    for _, task := range couponArray.tasks {
        // Prepare GraphQL to be sent off to test a promo code
        GraphQLQuery := CreateGraphQLQuery(taskDataV2, parsedSessionCookie, testProduct_ProductID)
        // Test Coupon
        CouponValue, err := TestCoupon(*parsedURL, GraphQLQuery, &taskData.ProxyURL, client)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
            return nil, err
        }
        // Redacted return code
        // Wait Time Between to avoid ratelimiting
        time.Sleep(350 * time.Millisecond)
    }

    // assume we return some data here, just as an example
    return &utilities.WebsiteData{}, nil
}
```

And `TestCoupon`:

```golang
func TestCoupon(domain url.URL, GraphQLquery string, proxyURL *url.URL, client *http.Client) (util.PromoCode, error) {
    var parsedData util.ShopifyPromoResponse

    GRAPHQL_URL := ParsedURLtoString(domain) + "/testData"
    // Make the Request
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, GRAPHQL_URL, strings.NewReader(GraphQLquery))
    PrintHeaders(&request.Header)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return util.PromoCode{}, err
    }
    request.Header = util.Headers
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return util.PromoCode{}, err
    }
        // Redacted return code
    // assume we return some promo code here, just as an example
    return util.PromoCode{}, nil
}
```

---

> Even after updating it to remove the mutex and create and use a new HTTP client, the headers still combine somehow.

Looking at your `TestCoupon` function:

```golang
request.Header = util.Headers
```

That line effectively replaces the entire `Header` of the `request`, which means it could be discarding any `Cookie` headers that were previously set (by the `http.Client` when it executed `Do`). The client's cookie jar automatically sets the `Cookie` header from the jar just before it executes the request.

Instead of replacing the entire header, you could update only the specific headers you are interested in, something like this:

```golang
request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, GRAPHQL_URL, strings.NewReader(GraphQLquery))
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return util.PromoCode{}, err
}

for k, v := range util.Headers {
    request.Header[k] = v
}
```

That way, you keep the `Cookie` header that `http.Client` set from the cookie jar, and any other headers that Go's HTTP package might automatically set.

Comment: I created a function like this and it printed it out correctly, but when printing out response.Request.Header (the request made), the cookie header provided is upwards of 20,000+ characters long after only a few tries, as well as the session tokens from each of the goroutines called being in that cookie (printed out just the session token), meaning that all the CookirJars are combining in a way. This is shows by after a few requests the web server starts errors as the cookie is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Even after updating it to remove the mutex and create and use a new HTTP client, the headers still combine somehow. Let me know if any more code is needed as this sure is a weird issue.

Comment: @makors Sure thing. I have edited the answer with one more suggestion, to address your comment.